# Install linux on separate drive without messing up the windows 10 boot?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, windows, system-installation, boot-loader

Would like to install Linux Mint, and I think the process is made difficult when windows 10 is already installed. Too many options to take and not knowing which one works the best. I want it to be a windows 10 PC but with a separate drive that runs Linux and its apps. I was going to install but found out PC will first boot to linux not windows. And that the linux installer (ubquitious) accidently installs on windows or something even when i tell it not to. So now im unsure about what to do.

Comment: Resize the partition using the windows control panel, then install linux on the not partitioned space. Other thing you must use EFI or Legacy boot on linux exactly like windows are configured.If you are using EFI in windows, then linux must be installed as EFI, if you are using Legacy boot on Windows, so then Linux must be installed on legacy mode. Some bios accept the two forms, and that maybe is the root of your problem.

Comment: how do i use EFI boot for linux? Its what windows uses i think

Comment: You just need to configure your bios to boot as EFI (if windows are really using it!), and then instead of selecting the CDROM for boot, you will select the EFI image. This depends very much on your bios, but try to search on boot options something like CDROM EFI or efi images, and then select the proper option.

Comment: on which drive should i have the bootloader?

Comment: In efi configuration this does not matter, you must have the EFI image in a special efi FAT32 partition on some of this drives, and them configure EFI BIOS SETUP with the right efi file to boot to your new system. The EFI partition is a FAT32 partition in the beginning of your hard drive, normally on the windows hard drive. You probably already have it, if you are using Windows. Windows has a good partition manager on the Control Panel, you probably will see a small fat32 partition called efi at this partitioner, and you will be able to resize the windows partition to install Linux.